# where is fmap (or how to apply a fn to every value of a map)

Tags: clojure

I am trying to apply a function to every value of a map. [`fmap`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.generic.functor/fmap) does the job. But what namespace has it moved to?

I also have written the below implementation, but I think this could be better -

```
(defn map-over
  [f m]
  (->>
   (map (fn [[k v]]
         {k (f v)})
        m)
   (into {})))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [migration page](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go) shows that `clojure.contrib.generic` has been migrated to [`algo.generic`](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/).