# Converting lists to sets in a list of maps of lists in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a list of maps where each key is associated with a list of strings.

I would like to convert each of these string list to sets instead.

```
(def list-of-maps-of-lists '({:a ["abc"]} {:a ["abc"]} {:a ["def"]} {:x ["xyz"]} {:x ["xx"]}))
```

This is my best attempt so far:

```
(flatten (map (fn [amap] (for [[k v] amap] {k (set v)})) list-of-maps-of-lists))

=> ({:a #{"abc"}} {:a #{"abc"}} {:a #{"def"}} {:x #{"xyz"}} {:x #{"xx"}})
```

What is the idiomatic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer solving such problems with [fmap](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.generic.functor/fmap) function from `clojure.contrib`:

```
(map (partial fmap set)
     list-of-maps-of-lists)
```

**Update:** According to [This Migration Guide](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go), `fmap` has been moved to [clojure.algo.generic.functor](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj) namespace of [algo.generic](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/) library.

Comment: Thanks! That looks really useful. According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847681/where-is-fmap-or-how-to-apply-a-fn-to-every-value-of-a-map it's been moved to here: https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/

Answer (score 4):

This is *very* similar to your solution.

Using list comprehension:

```
(map
  #(into {} (for [[k v] %] [k (set v)]))
  list-of-maps-of-lists)
```

Alternative:

```
(map
  #(zipmap (keys %) (map set (vals %)))
  list-of-maps-of-lists)
```

Comment: Another alternative: `(map #(apply merge (map (fn [[k v]] {k (set v)}) %)) list-of-maps-of-lists)`

Comment: And another: `(map (partial reduce-kv (fn [a k v] (assoc a k (set v))) {}) list-of-maps-of-lists)`